# Bootstrap navbar does not work when minimising browsers

Tags: html, responsive-design

I have a bootstrap navbar such as below. It works fine however when I minimise the window, the navbar becomes two times thicker than the navbar that appears on maximised window and the toggle do not show any menu. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Categories<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="index1.php">Index 1</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php">Index 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Can you show us how js and css file are included ?

Comment: @AlexandreT, I edited the code, please have a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have only one line, your button tag have to be in the div.navbar-header
And to work properly, change your data-target to"#navbarCollapse"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Categories<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="index1.php">Index 1</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="index2.php">Index 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </nav></body></html>
```